# Gitignore does not ignore a subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory like so:

```
.gitignore
myapp/
  instance/
  ...
```

And my `.gitignore` fire looks like this:

```
/myapp/instance
```

I would like the instance folder and its contents not to be pushed when committing however it always does. Why is this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you already commit the files in the subfolder? If so, then you need to untrack them first:
`git update-index --assume-unchanged instance/*`

Also, I think you meant "file" and not "fire" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1) In your .gitgnore, you should suffix your folder with "/": `/myapp/instance/` (assuming "instance" is a folder)

2) If you've already committed stuff from that folder, you'll need to remove it as follows:

```
 git rm -r --cached . 
 git add .
 git commit -m 'Removed all files that are in the .gitignore' 
 git push origin master
```